# How to access NSURLResponse in different class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have following zipfile class which performs downloading of my zip file. I have a file name associated with my zip file. I need to know the filename to pass on to the viewcontroller class. Whenever I try to access the value in from a different class, it always returns me null. I actually want to know how can I use the responseString from ZipFile and use it in ViewController.

/***ZipFile.m***/

```
-(NSString *) downloadZipFile{


fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
directoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ZipFiles.zip", directoryPath];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com/id=123"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSError *error1;
urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error1];

[fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:urlData attributes:nil];

[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:filePath toDestination:directoryPath];
NSLog(@"Finished unzipping database");

Tab_Table_WinAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[[Tab_Table_WinAppDelegate alloc] init] autorelease];
[appDelegate loadingViewControllerDidFinish];

NSString *total = [self total]; // returns value here
return total;
}


- (NSString *)total {


NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *fileName = [response suggestedFilename];
NSLog(@"Value : %@", fileName);

return fileName;
   }
```

/****ViewController.m****/

```
- (CGSize)imageSizeAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
if (index < [self imageCount]) {

    ZipFile *map = [[ZipFile alloc]init];
    size.width = [[map total] floatValue]; // returns null here

    [map release];
}
return size;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ZipFile *map = [[ZipFile alloc]init];
```

That creates a new ZipFile, which probably isn't what you want to do. You'll need some way to pass the ZipFile object you're actually interested in to the controller.

Comment: Thank you. But I did not clearly understand what you mean ? How can I pass ZipFile object into my controller ?